# why cannot I edit my `hosts` file?

Tags: macos, terminal, network, finder, hosts

I'm trying to edit my hosts file, because doing `ssh <some host in hosts>` fails to translate to ip.

according to the Finder UI it is found under:

[image]
however when trying to run `cat hosts` from the terminal I get an error:

```
➜  /etc  cat hosts
cat: hosts: No such file or directory
```

I tried to create a new hosts file but then I see another one is created next to the first one

[image]

but when I try to edit the second `hosts` I need to duplicate to anther destination. I copy it to `/etc` and again the first problem occurs.

I have tried to change the permissions to everyone can read and write. But yet it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be a way to have two identically named files in the /etc folder. Can you do a Get Info on the original and verify the Name & Extension (and that the extension is not hidden, and that there are no spaces at the end of the name)?

Comment: one was `hosts.txt`

Comment: That can happen if you create the file from scratch in TextEdit (or a similar app) and simply save it in the /etc/ folder and aren't extremely vigilant about the extension as well as the "hide extension" option.

Answer (score 6):

Usually only the root user is allowed to modify the file `hosts`.

To do that and fix your hosts file or your /etc folder (depending where you applied your read/write permissions) follow these steps:

1. Throw away your newly created `hosts` file (but not the old one!)
2. Repair your permissions with `Disk Utility`.
   [image]
3. Open Terminal and enter `sudo nano /etc/hosts` and hit <kbd>↵</kbd>
4. Enter your password (it will not be shown!) and hit <kbd>↵</kbd>
   The standard hosts file in Yosemite looks like this:
   [image: nano]
5. Edit your `hosts` file.
   The format for each line is IP-address, then a tab or a single space and the hostname(s). Terminate the file with an empty trailing line.
6. write the changes to disk with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> followed by <kbd>↵</kbd>
   and exit nano with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>
7. Enter `exit`, hit <kbd>↵</kbd> and quit `Terminal.app`

As an alternative for the steps 3-7 you may download and install [hosts.prefpane](http://permanentmarkers.nl/software.html) and enter your additional hosts there.

Answer (score 0):

Just Change what you want to change on the duplicate, then replace the old `hosts` file.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found to change hosts settings is to:

1) Make a duplicate (which you already have done)

2) Move the duplicate to a new location, such as the desktop

3) Make another duplicate on the desktop and rename it "hosts ORIGINAL" so you know it is the original hosts file, in case you need to revert back.

4) Make the changes to "hosts" on the desktop and save it.

5) Delete or rename the "hosts" file in /etc to "hosts OLD"

6) Drag "hosts" from the desktop to /etc. (you may be asked for admin credentials)

Answer (score -1):

I encountered this problem in Yosemite 10.10.3. I couldn't find the solution until I started to think outside the box.

Most people don’t know it, but as default the ”/private/etc” folder and ”/private/etc/hosts” file permissions are set to ”read only”. So if you only change the ”hosts” file permissions to ”read and write” you still won’t be able to edit it in TextEdit. The ”hosts” file is locked due to the ”/private/etc” folder.  The trick is that you need to change both the permissions of ”/private/etc” folder then ”/private/etc/hosts” file.

sudo chmod 777 /private/etc;chmod 777 /private/etc/hosts;open -t /private/etc/hosts

I don't care if it is a bug or not!

Comment: You don't need write permissions to the containing folder to change a file's contents. That's not how the unix permission system works.

Comment: @JensErat you don't need write permissions to edit a file in place. But some gui editors write to a temp file in the same folder, and if that works they delete the old file and rename new to old. THAT process requires write-to-parent folder.